# How to edit .cshtml files in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a simple application that does basic CRUD operations on ASP.NET. The functionality is great but I want to edit the visuality. For example the textbox for int values is like this : 
[image]

I want it to be normal textbox without arrows. I also want bigger textbox for address value. 
How can I edit .cshtml files for that? The current code for an adress looks like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adres, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adres)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adres)
</div></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Adres)
```

Comment: Don't forget about @Html.TextAreaFor() in the case of address fields.